# Can I combine a manipulate plot and a plot of data from a file?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am fitting a theoretical equation for a complicated curve to some experimentally measured data. As you might be aware, algorithmically quantifying 'goodness of fit' for a complicated curve is something of a dark art...

I want to load the experimental data and display it in a graph, and then over the top have a manipulable plot of the generated curve superimposed, so that I can tweak the parameters by eye until the fit looks good.

I can plot the measured data, and I can plot the manipulable curve from theory, but I need them to be plotted on top of each other!

I'm having trouble getting it to show the two graphs at once though... is it possible?

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: check out `Show`

Comment: `Manipulate[ Show[ Plot[...], ListPlot[...]], {...}]`. This question has been asked many times, and of course is a duplicate.

Comment: `Plot[ <<>>, Epilog -> Points@expdata` is a good way too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Show` can help you, as in this example:

```
preMadePlot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
Manipulate[Show[
  preMadePlot,
  Plot[Sin[p x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
  ], {p, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! I was very close but misusing Show. Cheers!