# How do I combine a Plot and a ListLinePlot inside a Manipulate?

Tags: plotting

I have this [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) with a [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
Remove["Global`*"]
f[x_] := -x^3 + 2*x^2 + 5*x - 6
Manipulate[
 Plot[(f[x]), {x, -6, 6},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{a, f[a]}], 
    Point[{(a + h), f[a + h]}]},
  PlotRange -> {-10, 5},
  PlotLabel -> Row[
    {"Slope of Secant Line: m = ", {{(f[a + h]) - (f[a])}/{(a + h) - 
         a}}}]],
 "Change a or h",    
 {{a, 2.6, "a"}, -3, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{h, 0.51, "h"}, -1.01, 1.01, 0.02, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I want to combine `Plot` and `ListLinePlot` inside `Manipulate`.

```
a = 2.6
h = 0.51
p1 = {a, f[a]}
p2 = {(a + h), f[a + h]}
ListLinePlot[{p1, p2}]
```

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: It would help if you put more effort in your questions. Its rude to expect people making an effort answering your problem if you don't show any effort in crafting a [good question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I combine a manipulate plot and a plot of data from a file?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31528/can-i-combine-a-manipulate-plot-and-a-plot-of-data-from-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation for [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

Here done with `ListPlot` just as illustrative example, but the same applies to `ListLinePlot` or any other graphics.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[m x + n, {x, 0, 10}
   , PlotRange -> {0, 10}
   , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
   ]
  , ListPlot[Range[10]]

  ], {{m, 1}, 0, 10}, {{n, 0}, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]